# Converting a list from one type to another using implicit conversion operator in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have the following:

```
Public Class Object1()

    ...

    Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal object As Object1) As Object2
        Return New Object2(...)
    End Operator

    ...
End Class

Public Class Object2
    ...
End Class
```

Now if I create a `List(Of Object1)` and try to use in a function with the following prototype: `DoSomething(ByVal objects As List(Of Object2))`

I get `Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object1) cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Object2)'`

Comment: Thats what I figured... Is there a way to use ConvertAll()?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you know how to convert type `A` to type `B` you don't know how to convert type `List(Of A)` to `List(Of B)`. But you could use [`List.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
dim list1 = new List(Of Object1)
list1.Add(new Object1())
dim list2 as List(Of Object2) ' = list1 doesn't compile
list2 = list1.ConvertAll(Function(obj1) CType(obj1, object2))
```

This will use your conversion operator.